# Multiple Screen support using java code in android

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I created a app in android using java code , I did'nt use any xml for design .My APP is not supporting multi screen , even thought I changed the margin to dp, margin size is getting differ for different screen.I gone through all website with long search changed as per but still not supporting for different screens.I given in manifest file also .How to resolve it using java ?? 
My code:

```
     RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
      myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);



     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

        lp.setMargins(pxToDp(10),pxToDp(100),pxToDp(25),0);



            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,m1.getId());

            lp1.setMargins(pxToDp(10),pxToDp(100),pxToDp(25),0);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,m4.getId());
                lp2.setMargins(pxToDp(10),pxToDp(100),pxToDp(25),0);




                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    lp3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,m3.getId());

                    lp3.setMargins(pxToDp(10),pxToDp(100),pxToDp(25),0);

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp4= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    lp4.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                    lp4.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                    lp4.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);




                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp5= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    lp5.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
                    lp5.setMargins(0,40,0,10);

                    lp5.setMargins(0,pxToDp(40),0,pxToDp(10));

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams= 
                            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


                    buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,m5.getId());
                    buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT,m5.getId());
                    buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM,m5.getId());

                    buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);




                    buttonParams.setMargins(pxToDp(80),pxToDp(230),pxToDp(80),pxToDp(50));


                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams1= 
                            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


                    buttonParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,m5.getId());
                    buttonParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT,m5.getId());
                    buttonParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM,m5.getId());

                    buttonParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);



                    buttonParams1.setMargins(pxToDp(150),pxToDp(270),pxToDp(150),pxToDp(170));


                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp6= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    lp6.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,m1.getId());
                    lp6.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT,m1.getId());
                    lp6.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,m1.getId());
                    lp6.setMargins(pxToDp(25),pxToDp(40),pxToDp(25),0);




                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp7= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);



                    lp7.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,m2.getId());
                    lp7.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT,m2.getId());
                    lp7.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,m2.getId());

                    lp7.setMargins(pxToDp(25),pxToDp(40),pxToDp(25),0);


                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp8= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    lp8.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,m3.getId());
                    lp8.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT,m3.getId());
                    lp8.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,m3.getId());
                    lp8.setMargins(pxToDp(25),pxToDp(40),pxToDp(25),0);


                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp9= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    lp9.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,m4.getId());
                    lp9.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT,m4.getId());
                    lp9.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,m4.getId());
                    lp9.setMargins(pxToDp(25),pxToDp(40),pxToDp(25),0);




                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams3= 
                            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);



                    textParams3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,m5.getId());

                    textParams3.setMargins(pxToDp(265),pxToDp(5),pxToDp(170),pxToDp(150));

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams4= 
                            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


                    textParams4.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,m5.getId());
                    textParams4.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT,m5.getId());
                    textParams4.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,m5.getId());
                    textParams4.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,t3.getId());
                    textParams4.setMargins(pxToDp(120),pxToDp(90),pxToDp(65),pxToDp(135));



                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams5= 
                            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


                    textParams5.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,m5.getId());
                    textParams5.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT,m5.getId());
                    textParams5.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,m5.getId());
                    textParams5.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,t4.getId());
                    textParams5.setMargins(pxToDp(230),pxToDp(150),pxToDp(130),pxToDp(110));



                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams6= 
                            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


                    textParams6.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,m5.getId());
                    textParams6.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT,m5.getId());
                    textParams6.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,m5.getId());
                    textParams6.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,t5.getId());
                    textParams6.setMargins(pxToDp(155),pxToDp(190),pxToDp(60),pxToDp(90));








                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams7= 
                            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


                    textParams7.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,m5.getId());
                    textParams7.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT,m5.getId());
                    textParams7.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,m5.getId());
                    textParams7.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,t6.getId());
                    textParams7.setMargins(pxToDp(270),pxToDp(230),pxToDp(125),pxToDp(80));




                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams2= 
                            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


                    textParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,m5.getId());
                    textParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT,m5.getId());

                    textParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM,m5.getId());

                    textParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

                    textParams2.setMargins(pxToDp(270),pxToDp(180),pxToDp(150),pxToDp(400));


                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp11= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    lp11.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,m1.getId());
                    lp11.setMargins(0,pxToDp(40),pxToDp(40),0);



                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp12= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    lp12.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,m2.getId());
                    lp12.setMargins(0,pxToDp(38),pxToDp(50),0);

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp13= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    lp13.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,m4.getId());

                    lp13.setMargins(pxToDp(35),pxToDp(38),0,0);


                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp10= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);



                    lp10.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM,e1.getId());
                    lp10.setMargins(pxToDp(190),0,pxToDp(150),pxToDp(10));
```

Comment: Why don't you just use XML layouts for your activities in the first place?

Comment: No app should be only in java design not with xml .More over I gave content view as layout name .

Comment: It should work proprly. check you pxToDp() function

Comment: public static int pxToDp(int px)
 {
     return (int) (px / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
 }

Comment: This is a function for it , only margin size getting different position for different screen , it is possible to set margin as auto resize according to screen ???